# ganttchart with range in title

Tags: pgfgantt

I want to have a range of months (Months 1-3, 4-6... etc) as the title of my gant chart, however when I do:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\def\printrange#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(1+#1*#2)}\pgfmathresult%
  -%
  \pgfmathparse{int((1+#1)*#2)}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,hgrid]{1}{12}
  \gantttitlelist[title list options=%
  {var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x%
    using "Months \printrange{\y}{3}"
    %using "Months \y"
  }
  ]{0,...,3}{3}\\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

I get the error `Incomplete \iffalse`. I am not sure why since if I just do `\printrange{2}{3}` outside a ganttchart I get the correct printed range.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use pgf or ganttchart, I can't find the error. A proposal with `Expl3`

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfgantt}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentCommand{\printrange}{m m}
    {
        \int_eval:n { 1+#1*#2 } - \int_eval:n { (1+#1)*#2 }
    }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,hgrid]{1}{12}
        \gantttitlelist[title list options=%
                {var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x%
                    using "\printrange{\y}{3}"
                }
        ]{0,...,3}{3}
    \end{ganttchart}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That does exactly what I want. Make me wonder even more why `pgfmathparse` doesn't work.

Comment: I found. By putting \protect in front of \printrange your code works fine. using "Months \protect\printrange{\y}{3}"

Comment: That's great. Yes, replacing `\def` with `\protected\def` fixed the issue in my code.